# Is there a Hindu equivalent of the Buddhist Dukkha?

Tags: scripture, belief, moksha, life, buddhism

I really like the Buddhist teaching on suffering-unsatisfactoriness (Dukkha), a characteristic of existence and how to get rid of it.

I was wondering if there was a Hindu equivalent? A similar discourse on suffering, omnipresent in ordinary life, born of desire and on ways to get rid of it.

While searching I found this: [Dukkha in Hinduism.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dukkha#Hinduism)

But it's a little short, so if you ever have any additional resources on the subject, don't hesitate!

Thank you.

Comment: Dukkha is a Pāli equivalent of the Sanskrit term duḥkha, it's spoken quite much in Sāṅkhya, and is also accepted in Vedānta. However, duḥkha doesn't have exactly same meaning in Vaidika and Bauddha darśanas. Bauddha darśanas have a more complicated understanding of duḥkha, where it indicates anityatā, etc. too. So, duḥkha as an āryasatya is not accepted in Vaidika darśanas, but they do have their own conception of duḥkha, which pertains to saṁsāra. For Bauddhas, even the idea of ātman is duḥkha, which is not true for Vaidikas.